# ObjectBox query all objects with a String propery from array

Tags: android, objectbox

ObjectBox has `QueryBuilder`'s method `in` with arrays of `long` and `int` as a parameter:

```
QueryBuilder<T> in(Property property, int[] values)
```

However, there are some cases when the `id` of an object is `String`. How can we query a list of elements using an array of their `String` uids?

For example, we are caching Android Contacts and want to find subsets basing on their `LOOKUP_KEY`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This feature is tracked here: https://github.com/objectbox/objectbox-java/issues/361

For now, you would have to combine individual "equal" conditions with an "or" operator.